# In Yii2 make db query(include 'join' expression) to oracle, cannot fetch any result

Tags: php, oracle, yii2, oracle-call-interface

Here's the code in controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $result = new RestResult();
    try {
        $query = TaskMgr::find()
            ->join('INNER JOIN', EqpInfo::tableName(), EqpInfo::tableName() . '.EQP_COD =' . TaskMgr::tableName() . '.EQP_COD')

            ->select([TaskMgr::tableName() . '.EQP_COD', TaskMgr::tableName() . '.TASK_STA', TaskMgr::tableName() . '.TASK_DATE', TaskMgr::tableName() . '.BUSINESS_NATURE', EqpInfo::tableName() . '.EQP_SORT_NAME', EqpInfo::tableName() . '.EQP_VART_NAME', EqpInfo::tableName() . '.USE_UNT_NAME', EqpInfo::tableName() . '.USE_UNT_ADDR', EqpInfo::tableName() . '.INST_AREA_NAME', EqpInfo::tableName() . '.MAKE_UNT_NAME']);
        $result->content = $query->asArray(true)->all();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result->error = $e->getMessage();
        $result->content = [];
        $result->message = ["error" => Yii::t('rest', "Server error.")];
    } finally {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

and I got empty array.[as pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS5yH.png), I thought it might be the problem of QueryBuilder, so I simply excute the sql script in index action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $y = Yii::$app->get('db2')->createCommand('SELECT * FROM "TB_TASK_MGR" INNER JOIN "V_EQPINFO" ON "V_EQPINFO".EQP_COD ="TB_TASK_MGR".EQP_COD')
        ->queryAll();
    return var_dump($y);
}
```

and I got a empty array again.
but when I ran the sql script in Navicat, I got some rows.[as pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZJRx.png), that means the sql result is not empty. I thought it might some problems with my DBConnection, so I tried change the action as :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $y = Yii::$app->get('db2')->createCommand('SELECT * FROM "TB_TASK_MGR"')
        ->queryAll();
    return var_dump($y);
}
```

and I got some rows, that means there's no problem in DBConnection, the only difference is the 'join' expression.

I use xampp to deploy site, php version is 5.6.23. oracle client installed and remote oracle version is 11g. php.ini config oci as

```
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
```

Please help me find out why is this, is it because some bugs in php_pdo_oci.dll? and how to excute sql with 'join' in yii2 to oracle.

Comment: I can see two possibilities here …
1) Are you sure you are using same DB schema while running the query from Navicat (SQL Client) and PHP?
2) Are you using/applying any row level security (RLS/VPD) on a schema from which PHP is attempting to run this query?

Comment: Thinks for your inspiring! I used different dsn which has the same table structure but different data. how stupid am i.

Comment: Thanks for your update @Liu. Can you mark the question answered pls?